# destructure object in javascript es6 when keys are integers

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, destructuring

When we have an object in JS like

```
var obj = {a: "apple", p: "pen"};
```

then we can destructure it as follows

```
 var {a, p} = obj; /* a = 'apple', p = 'pen' */
```

i want to know in case when keys are integers, how can we destructure it ? since we cannot declare integers as variable name

```
 var obj = {0: 'pineapple', 1: 'pen'};
```

Comment: you can use `keys = Object.keys(obj)` it will give the array of all the keys, then you can access any value by using the keys, like `a=obj[keys[index]]`, is this what you want ??

Comment: Is this an array-like object such as `arguments` or `NodeList`? Or is this an object where there are other string properties? If it's array-like, you can use array destructuring.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just like any other [assigning to new variable names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

```
var {0:a, 1:b} = obj;
```

Comment: @4castle, no, because the obj doesn't implement the iterable interface.